# Magento 2 Create Controller rendering Blank Page

Tags: magento2, php, router

I am new to Magento and I tried this tutorial where I will create a controller for Magento 2.
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-controllers-magento-2.html

My problem is: When I try to go to the `http://<yourbrowser>/helloworld` or `http://<yourbrowser>/helloworld/index/index`, it renders a blank page.

I followed everything from the tutorial, just I renamed the `/vendorName/moduleName` to `/custom/helloWorld`

Here are the codes: **app/code/custom/helloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="helloworld" id="helloworld">
            <module name="custom_helloWorld"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**app/code/custom/helloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace custom\helloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
        //Pagefactory is used to initialize the layout.
    }
}
```

**app/code/custom/helloWorld/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="custom\helloWorld\Block\Index" name="helloworld_index_index" template="custom_helloWorld::index.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

**app/code/custom/helloWorld/Block/Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace custom\helloWorld\Block;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

}
```

**app/code/custom/helloWorld/view/frontend/templates/index.phtml**

```
<h2>Welcome to HELLO WORLD PAGE!</h2>
```

I already tried to flush the cache but same problem occur.

I hope you can help me. Thank you so much in advance!!

---

**UPDATE:** So I just copied whatever is in the link: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-controllers-magento-2.html

And still renders a blank page...

Comment: create module after you run `php bin/magento s:up` && `php bin/magento s:s:d -f` ???

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you start vendor name and module name with small character.
Ex: "app/code/custom/helloWorld/Block/Index.php"

But it should be like "app/code/Custom/HelloWorld/Block/Index.php"

Kindly refer below link for create custom module:

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-controllers-magento-2.html

Comment: I changed it to "app/code/Custom/HelloWorld/Block/Index.php". And correct the paths on Block, Controller, etc, view folders. As well as the registration.php.

Result when I try to access http://<yourbrowser>/helloworld:

404 Not Found Error.

Answer (score 0):

Update Your helloworld_index_index.xml with this ,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="helloworld_index_index" template="custom_helloWorld::index.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

No need of block file...
flush the Cache and Run in Browser it works fine...

Comment: Thank you Kishor. I tried, but 404 Error not Found occurs when I run in browser :(

Comment: may be you doing some wrong with the syntax ...have you run command setup:upgrade?

Comment: yes, I did run the command setup:upgrade. Still Blank Page.

Comment: have your magento work fine? Although Follow this blog [link](https://meetanshi.com/blog/magento-2-module-development/)...Its work fine

Answer (score 0):

First rename your module to Custom/HelloWorld - Module name and name space should be having first letter capital ..Its good practise.

Than change code like below

app/code/Custom/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="helloworld" id="helloworld">
            <module name="Custom_HelloWorld"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

app/code/Custom/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Custom\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
        //Pagefactory is used to initialize the layout.
    }
}
```

app/code/Custom/HelloWorld/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Custom\HelloWorld\Block\Index" name="helloworld_index_index" template="Custom_HelloWorld::index.phtml" />

    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

app/code/Custom/HelloWorld/Block/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block;
class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

}
```

app/code/Custom/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/index.phtml

```
<h2>Welcome to HELLO WORLD PAGE!</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you Parul. Copied all your code, except, I corrected the `app/code/Custom/HelloWorld/Block/Index.php` **namespace and class**, I flushed the Magento Cache, and access the /helloworld url. Still 404 Not Found Error occurs.

Comment: Do run command php bin/magento setup:di:compile and let me know if any problem occurs